# ModernCV: Increase space between words in extrainfo

Tags: moderncv

I created `extrainfo` in my CV with class `moderncv`. Now I have there few entries, like:

```
\extrainfo{\textbf{\emph{{\Large Personal Info:}}} \\Birthday:  15.11.1901 \\Nationality:   English \\Marital Status:    married}
```

It looks good. But I would like that all the entries after `:` are in the same line. What I get, like:

> Birthday:     15.11.1901
>   Nationality:    English
>   Marital Status:   married

But I'd like to have 'English', 'married' and '15.11.1901' under each other in one line.

Could you please help me here?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please provide a minimum working example that compiles and shows the problem.  You will save us all the need to guess what you are intending and the time to type in what you already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the environments `minipage` and `tabular` to get the wanted result.

The changed code is:

```
\extrainfo{%
\begin{minipage}{3.8cm}% start minipage
\raggedright\textbf{\emph{{\Large Personal Info:}}} % heading
\begin{tabular}{ll} % start table
Birthday:& 15.11.1901 \\
Nationality: & English \\
Marital Status: &  married
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
} % end extrainfo
```

With the following MWE (including the new part of code)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % \rmdefault
%\nopagenumbers{} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
%\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{Jun-Sep, 2011} 
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % for the 'classic' style

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
%\extrainfo{\textbf{\emph{{\Large Personal Info:}}} \\Birthday:  15.11.1901 \\Nationality:   English \\Marital Status:    married}

\extrainfo{%
\begin{minipage}{3.8cm}% 
\raggedright\textbf{\emph{{\Large Personal Info:}}} 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Birthday:& 15.11.1901 \\
Nationality: & English \\
Marital Status: &  married
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
}

\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}


\end{document}
```

you get the wanted first page:

[image: first page of resulting pdf]