# moderncv 2.0 : Banking Style - Left align Header

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, moderncv

I would prefer a decuttered look of the header in the moderncv banking style.
Basically I want my name incdugint the title of the CV centered in one line at the top (similar to the way it is in the banking style)

But all the other information should be nicely left aligned including the additional info and the social tags (linkedin etc.) I want a big photo on the right side with the possibility to alter the x position and the size.

i found a few solutions [oldSolution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275792/custom-header-and-banking-body-style-mixed-in-moderncv) [oldSolution2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173284/moderncv-banking-style-how-to-move-the-title-block-all-the-way-to-the-left) but they do not work with the updated moderncv.

EDIT:

Essentially it should look like this:

[image]

Which is a variaton of what is posted on here [Solution1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275792/custom-header-and-banking-body-style-mixed-in-moderncv?noredirect=1&lq=1). But this only works with an old version of moderncv. I would like the title of the CV to be just as it is in the banking style but centered.Essentially what i am after is the banking style cv but with a good placement of a picture. Without a picture the look is nice. With a picture it looks cluttered.

If this is possible i would like to have the option! to put the additonal information block in the middle. It would be a 3 column design then. This way i could missuse this filed for marital status and other stuff wich is only a standard in europe simillar to how it is done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374898/moderncv-increase-space-between-words-in-extrainfo?rq=1).

Furthermore it would be nice to have the option to either add a line between the postcode/city and the rest or not.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: A sketch of the expected output would be helpful here.

Comment: I just uploaded a picture to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to solve your several questions at last an recreation of the head for style `banking` of class `moderncv`, version 2.1.0 is needed.

The name and title is written with an centered line, then we need a tabular environment for the details, included in an `minipage` and an box for the image. At last we need a new line centered for the quote, if needed ...

Please see the following MWE (important code changings are marked with `<=======`)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}\\[1.5em]}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
    \centering \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}% <=================
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\namestyle{~|~}\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]% <================
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
      \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T}
      \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
    \end{adjustbox}
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\vspace{2.5em}
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}%
\makeatother

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}% <=====================================================
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[94pt][0pt]{example-image-golden-upright} % <===================== 0pt for no rule around the image
\quote{`` A witty and playful quote''}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf

[image: resulting cv]